# remover o esconder direccion url nginx

Tags: php, url, nginx

quiero remover o esconder una direccion
https://ejemplo.com/themes/last/pages/mensajes/index.php

quede asi
https://ejemplo.com/mensajes/index.php

intente con rewrite, pero creo que no lo estoy usando bien.

Answer (score 0):

Redireccionar la url con un 301 "permanent" https://ejemplo.com/themes/last/pages/mensajes/index.php a https://ejemplo.com/mensajes/index.php

```
rewrite ^themes/last/pages/(.*)$ $1 permanent;
```

Ahora que ha redireccionado a https://ejemplo.com/mensajes/index.php cargamos el valor que debería tener con **themes/last/pages/mensajes/index.php**

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ themes/last/pages/$1 last;
```